# How to set wget time waiting between X Downloads?

Tags: bash, time, wget

I have a links.txt, in it, there are 1000 Links (link per line).

My command is:

```
wget -i links.txt -O linkoutfiles
```

So I want to make time waiting between each 200 link downloads.

eEx : 5 second for each 200 link

I don't want a command:  '-w' because this command makes the links wait for each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `wget` doesn't have an option to pause after a number of downloads, but you can easily script it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=0
for link in $(cat links.txt); do
    wget $link -O - >> linkoutfiles
    let counter++
    if ! ((counter % 200)); then
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

Not sure what exactly you want with `linkoutfiles`, tho, but the above should mimic what `wget` does but with a pause of 5 seconds after each 200th download.

**UPDATE** - If you insist, you can run it whole directly from your terminal prompt:

```
counter=0; for link in $(cat links.txt); do wget $link -O - >> linkoutfiles ; let counter++ ; if ! ((counter % 200)); then sleep 5 ; fi ; done
```

It's just more convenient and manageable to have it as a separate shell script. This has nothing to do with PHP or anything of the sort and will work in pretty much any `bash` console (and even in most builds of the plain ol' `sh`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
i want make command only in linux commands not for Php.
how can i make this.
best ragards mr zwer :)

Comment: if wget not have a time wait between 200 link downloads. what other commands can work with my situation ?

Comment: @BestDevo - This is not PHP, it's a regular bash/shell script (something you've tagged your question with). You could, technically, type it directly in the terminal if you wanted to, it's just less cryptic and more convenient to have it as a separate script.

Comment: Work perfectly 
you are a genius ^^ . thank you so much.